# How to rotate image in relation to mouse position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to do this effect: http://metatroid.com/articles at the top of the page but I can't get it to rotate with just the code they given.

```
 var img = $('.image');
 if(img.length > 0){
     var offset = img.offset();
     function mouse(evt){
         var center_x = (offset.left) + (img.width()/2);
         var center_y = (offset.top) + (img.height()/2);
         var mouse_x = evt.pageX; var mouse_y = evt.pageY;
         var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
         var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 90; 
         img.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
         img.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
         img.css('-o-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
         img.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
       }
$(document).mousemove(mouse);
 }
```

So I put this code under my javascript function and changed my image class to 'image' but it still wouldn't rotate.

Is there any other jquery or css markup associated with this or any tips you can give me to 
make this work? I'm still kind of new to this so any help is really appreciated. Thank you.

**UPDATE**:
I managed to get the rotate effect to work, but it wouldn't rotate on the right axis. 
Here's the url for what I'm working on: http://www.lifetime-watches.com/test/i_watches.html

How do I move the axis/pivot so it'll work perfectly?

Comment: Can you provide us the link to the file if it's hosted?

Comment: I didn't get any errors, and I put the link up at http://jsfiddle.net/KmgNJ/1/. Thank you.

Comment: Fixed your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/22Feh/

Comment: It works fine for me, [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22Feh/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you only define the function mouse, and only set the event handler, if img.length is > 0.  The script is located in the head, and executed before the body can load, so there is no image.

Fix - move the script into the body of the document after the  where the image is defined.  Also, your fiddle doesn't include jQuery (mootools instead).  Once you fix those two things it will work.

Comment: Thank you! This solves the problem! I still have much to learn about jquery. Thanks a lot.

Comment: UPDATE: I managed to get the rotate effect to work, but it wouldn't rotate on the right axis. Here's the url for what I'm working on: http://www.lifetime-watches.com/test/i_watches.html

How do I move the axis/pivot so it'll work perfectly?

Comment: It's because the center of the image is no longer the rotation point.  You're looking at a lot of math to fix that OR - modify the image so that its center IS the rotation point.  If you want a perfect-looking watch, you'll have to build a perfect-looking bighand.png.  Image height and width should be odd numbers with the middle pixel in both cases being the exact center of the hole in the watch hand.  If the circle is an even number of pixels in diameter you will get a wobbling effect.  Don't do any lighting effects on the watchhand because it will look weird when it's upside-down.

Comment: Here's a (slightly wobbly) example from your original fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/22Feh/5/