# How can I have an animation follow my cursor

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, rotation

So currently, if you hover over the compass the needle spins around, however, when you take your mouse off it just resets.

Is there a way that I can either:

- Make the needle follow wherever my mouse is when it is hovered over and if i took my mouse off at say the south position, the needle stay there

or

- spin round on hover like now but pause when i take my mouse off it and resume when i re-hover

the website can be found at

[newsunken.tumblr.com](http://newsunken.tumblr.com)

and my current code is...

```css
.arrow {
    background-image: url(compass.png);
}

.arrowhover {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -72px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 0s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0s ease-in-out;
}
```

(that is to stop the arrow from rotating when i take my mouse off)

and the spin code is

```css
.arrowhover:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(1440deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(1440deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 1.7s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1.7s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1.7s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1.7s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1.7s ease-in-out;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do it purely with CSS. you will have to use javascript to get the mouse x and y positions and when it is within the compass area rotate it according to the mouse position.

maybe this will be of use to you:
[How to rotate image in relation to mouse position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195825/how-to-rotate-image-in-relation-to-mouse-position)