# How to Rotate image that follows cursor in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have image that is following mouse's cursor.

HTML:

```
<img id="cow" src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/gakuseisean/ivista-2/128/Alarm-Arrow-Right-icon.png" height="30px" width="30px" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;"/>
```

Javascript:

```
var mouseXY = {};
$( document ).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
  mouseXY.X = event.pageX; 
  mouseXY.Y = event.pageY;
});
var iCow = $("#cow");
var cowInterval = setInterval(function()
{
  var cowXY = iCow.position();
  var diffX = cowXY.left - mouseXY.X;
  var diffY = cowXY.top - mouseXY.Y;
  var newX = cowXY.left - diffX / 1000;
  var newY = cowXY.top - diffY / 1000;
  iCow.css({left: newX, top: newY});
}, 10);
```

[**JSFiddle example**](https://jsfiddle.net/q9kn8ady/)

How can I rotate image in the direction of cursor?
I have tried to do it with `transform: rotate()`:

```
var cowInterval = setInterval(function()
{
  var cowXY = iCow.position();
  var diffX = cowXY.left - mouseXY.X;
  var diffY = cowXY.top - mouseXY.Y;
  var newX = cowXY.left - diffX / 1000;
  var newY = cowXY.top - diffY / 1000;
  var tan = diffX / diffY;
  var atan = Math.atan(tan);
  iCow.css({left: newX, top: newY, transform: "rotate(" +((-1)*atan - Math.PI/2)+ "rad)"});
}, 10);
```

but unsuccessfully

Comment: I guess the problem is with get `position()` . Even without moving , the position value keep changing just by transform rotate. You can see the console log. https://jsfiddle.net/q9kn8ady/4/

Comment: Above comment may not matter or the real cause but anyway for image rotate I found this fiddle which seems to be more accurate rotate. http://jsfiddle.net/22Feh/556/ from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195825/how-to-rotate-image-in-relation-to-mouse-position

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/22Feh/5/ :- answered in some comment in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195825/how-to-rotate-image-in-relation-to-mouse-position

Comment: @DipendraSingh it break when u try to move it.

Comment: @cjmling replace the image with yours

Comment: You can simplify your displacement logic with a vector class: https://jsfiddle.net/0x1dwqmk/ This is a start...

Answer (score 10):

You need to change only the transform(rotate) css property when changing the cursor postion, keeping in mind that the cursor actually changed position.

Add these two if-else condition to make the image rotate in the correct direction

```
 if(diffY > 0 && diffX > 0) {

    atan += 180; 
  }
 else if(diffY < 0 && diffX > 0) {

    atan -= 180;
  }
```

I suppose this is what you want.

```js
var mouseXY = {};
    $( document ).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
      mouseXY.X = event.pageX; 
      mouseXY.Y = event.pageY;
    });
    var iCow = $("#cow");
    var prevXY = {X: null, Y: null};
    var cowInterval = setInterval(function()
    {
    
      
      if(prevXY.Y != mouseXY.Y || prevXY.X != mouseXY.X && (prevXY.Y != null || prevXY.X != null)) {
      
      var cowXY = iCow.position();
      var diffX = cowXY.left - mouseXY.X;
      var diffY = cowXY.top - mouseXY.Y;
      var tan = diffY / diffX;
     
      var atan = Math.atan(tan)* 180 / Math.PI;;
       if(diffY > 0 && diffX > 0) {
      
       atan += 180; 
      }
      else if(diffY < 0 && diffX > 0) {
      
       atan -= 180;
      }
      
      prevXY.X = mouseXY.X;
      prevXY.Y = mouseXY.Y;
      iCow.css({transform: "rotate(" + atan + "deg)"});
    }
    }, 10);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="cow" src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/gakuseisean/ivista-2/128/Alarm-Arrow-Right-icon.png" height="30px" width="30px" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;"/>
```

Comment: Nice soultion for angle calculation, but the main problem is to combine movement with rotation

Comment: how do you want to execute movement. Could you please explain a little